# How can template identify what page it's being used on?

Tags: menus, templates

I have a template that is used for many different sections of my site (About, News, etc.). The nav bar needs to show a little graphic arrow below the section you're in. I was passing this via the template:

```
$page = 'about';
require('header.php');
```

...but then I realized that won't work since the template file I was editing is used for a bunch of different sections, not just 'about'.

So I need something on the `'page'` interface screen where I can somehow indicate the page that the user is on. Some ideas for solutions:

- Idea #1: does WordPress would set some kind of class on the 'body' tag to indicate the page you're on (like if it generated a slug based on the page name and added that as a class to the body tag)? Then just do everything I need to do in CSS without complicating things.
- Idea #2: some kind of built-in field on WordPress's 'page' admin that would let my header know what page it is on.
- Idea #3: I could make copies of my template for each major section. Very stupid way to go about it.

I would REALLY prefer to not go the whole extra-fields route, manually adding a metadata field to my pages, pulling it from the db on page load, etc. That seems like super overkill for just having a way to let my template code identify what page it is being used on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea #1 is correct if your template use `body_class()` like

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

In this case the body tag will be something like:

```
<body class="page page-id-6 page-template-default">
```

If the id of viewed page is 6 and template used is the default.

See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Page)

However, in pages the global `$post` variable is available even in the header and before calling `the_post()`. So `$post->post_name` will contain the slug of your page and you can make use of it as you want.

Comment: How frustrating that it doesn't also add a class based on the slug-- i.e. "page-about". Then I wouldn't have to rely on page ID numbers that could conceivably change.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you may not be aware of the following function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page
For example, you could use the following:

```
if (is_page( 'About' )) {
    // Do Something
}
```